# How to track AngularJS error - jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm running a project on a new PC, that works on other PC's. However when I run it here I get the error `jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]`.

I need to find a solution or a way to track the error and find what is causing it since I couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: Looks like you haven't installed `jQuery`...you should install all packages before attempting to run the project...

Comment: That's not it, it finds the jQuery file and all installations have been ran

Comment: Are you injecting jquery in angularjs dependencies? please share some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the error wasn't in jQuery, it was in angularytics.js, my adblocker was blocking some requests causing some dependencies to fail to load. When I disabled my adblocker it worked.